# Bubble sort with 2 different arrays

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

With

```
string[] z = { "arc", "banana", "cucumber", "deer", "elephant", "fiesta", "giga", "home", "idea", "jump" };
int[] y = { 189, 178, 65, 63, 200, 1000, 10, 15, 28, 20 };
```

I do a bubble sort of `z` ordered by `y`:

```
for (int i=0;i<=(y.length-2);i++){
                for (int j=(y.length-1); i<j;j--){
                    if (y[j]<y[j-1]){
                        int temp= y[j-1];
                        y[j-1]=y[j];
                        y[j]=temp;
                        String tempo=z[j-1];
                        z[j-1]=z[j];
                        tempo=z[j];
                    }
                }
            } 
 for (int i=y.length-1;i>0;i--){
 System.out.println(z[i]);}
```

After the print the output of the `z` is:

> jump, jump, jump, idea, idea, idea, idea, home, home, home

Why does sorting delete some values of `z`?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the temporary variable for the string array. With your code you save the content of `z[j-1]` in `tempo`, but you don't write it back to the array:

Instead of

```
String tempo=z[j-1];
z[j-1]=z[j];
tempo=z[j];
```

try this:

```
String tempo = z[j - 1];
z[j - 1] = z[j];
z[j] = tempo;
```

And in your output loop, you've got an [off by one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). Use `>=0`:

```
for (int i=y.length-1;i>=0;i--)
```